# Web service call...nullreference exception...property evaluation failed

Tags: vb.net

I try to make a call to my webservice and it gives me a "nullreference exception".  This code used to work.  The statuscode received from the call is OK: 200.  What could be happening?

```
'** Shipping.Carriers is my web service
dim myWs as Shipping.Carriers
dim strCode as string

Using myWS = New Shipping.Carriers
    myWS.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    '** when I pause here and check the status of the Web service...
    '** I see the Property Evaluation Failed on all of the functions in the web service

    myWS.Timeout = 400000

    '** the next line of code gives me the nullreference exception
    strCode = myWS.fUPS(my parameters go here)
    txtMsg.Text = strCode
End Using
```